# Como configuro o @media para celular?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho um celular Moto G e não consigo definir o `@media` para funcionar para ele.

Reduzindo a largura do navegador funciona perfeitamente, mas no dispositivo celular não se ajusta de acordo com o `@media`.

Abaixo coloquei o background do `form` para ficar cinza, e nada acontece. Veja o que fiz?

```
@media(max-width: 574px) {
.menutopo{
  display: none;
}
figure.logo{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #FF8922;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section.frmbuscaguia{
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px; 
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<figure class="logo">
            <p class="text-center"><img src="./imagens/logo.png" align="center"></p>
        </figure>


            <section class="frmbuscaguia">
            <h1>Buscar no Guia Comercial</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="buscar">
                <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
            </form>
            </section>
```

Comment: já tentou `@media screen and ()...`?

Comment: sim, já tentei!

Comment: Se for o chrome, so vai funcionar se limpar o histórico do navegador.

Comment: Já tentou o `@media only screen and (max-width: 574px)...` ?

Comment: @Newtech mas nada de funcionar

Comment: Configurou a tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` no `<head>`?

Comment: Posta uma imagem de como está ficando a página na tela de celular. Verifica se a meta tag viewport está configurada

Comment: Só para constar, fiz uns teste aqui e é muito provável que o seu problema seja o viewport mesmo, Use a `<meta name="viewport">` que a Bruna postou na resposta que vc vai resolver o problema. E para entender pq resolveu leia esse artigo https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

Eu testei seu código, sem nenhuma modificação e está funcionando corretamente.

Como você não enviou todo o código, a única coisa que eu fiz foi acrescentar um head e finalizar o código com o próprio padrão do bootstrap, vou mandar abaixo para você ver e conferir.

Você precisa verificar se está importando corretamente o css, ok?

Espero ter ajudado, lembrando que você precisa testar na resolução que está propondo no @media.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <style>
 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <figure class="logo">
  <p class="text-center"><img src="./imagens/logo.png" align="center"></p>
 </figure>

 <section class="frmbuscaguia">
  <h1>Buscar no Guia Comercial</h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="buscar">
   <button type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
  </form>
 </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cumprimentar é bom e muito educado, mas no Stack Overflow costumamos ser o mais breve e direto possível, não precisa enviar abraços nem dizer olá. Mesmo assim, essa é uma boa resposta.

Comment: hehe é costume de ser cordial sempre, mas valeu pela dica!